# TGifImage Transparency Issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am using TGifImage that is included with Delphi XE.

What I am trying to do is load a Gif from a File and and extract all the frames to a Bitmap.

This is what I did so far:

```
procedure ExtractGifFrames(FileName: string);
var
  Gif: TGifImage;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  try
    Gif.LoadFromFile(FileName);

    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.SetSize(Gif.Width, Gif.Height);

      for i := 0 to Gif.Images.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if not Gif.Images[i].Empty then
        begin
          Bmp.Assign(Gif.Images[i]);
          Bmp.SaveToFile('C:\test\bitmap' + IntToStr(i) + '.bmp');
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Gif.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    ExtractGifFrames(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;
```

The problem I am facing is with some transparency issue with a lot of different Gifs, and also size problems.

Here are some example bitmaps that were saved using my code above:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the results are not great, they have size and transparency issues.

I know the Gif Files themselves are not corrupt, because I can load them through my web browser and they display correctly without fault.

How can I load a Gif from File, assign each frame to Bitmap without losing any quality?

Comment: I found out the way how the key frames are realized. It's determined by the `GraphicControlExtension.Disposal` for each frame (if available). It means what the current frame should do with the already rendered buffer. As a source you can use what else than `TGIFRenderer`, the class which actually renders the animations. I'll try to compose an example in the evening (if someone wouldn't be faster :-) I have to go now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**For older Delphi Versions (Pre 2009):** Take a look at the code of `GIFImage` unit, you might want to check how `TGIFPainter` renders the images based on each Frame's `Disposal` method.

I have wrote a small code utilizing `TGIFPainter.OnAfterPaint` event handler to save the active frame to BMP, and do all the "hard work".

Note: `GIFImage` unit version 2.2 Release: 5 (23-MAY-1999)

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  public
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
    procedure AfterPaintGIF(Sender: TObject);
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
begin
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  try
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\test\test.gif');
    GIF.DrawOptions := GIF.DrawOptions - [goLoop, goLoopContinously, goAsync];
    GIF.AnimationSpeed := 1000; // Max - no delay
    FBitmap.Width := GIF.Width;
    FBitmap.Height := GIF.Height;
    GIF.OnAfterPaint := AfterPaintGIF;

    ProgressBar1.Max := Gif.Images.Count;
    ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    ProgressBar1.Smooth := True;
    ProgressBar1.Step := 1;

    // Paint the GIF onto FBitmap, Let TGIFPainter do the painting logic
    // AfterPaintGIF will fire for each Frame
    GIF.Paint(FBitmap.Canvas, FBitmap.Canvas.ClipRect, GIF.DrawOptions);
    ShowMessage('Done!');
  finally
    FBitmap.Free;
    GIF.Free;
    Button1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AfterPaintGIF(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (Sender is TGIFPainter) then Exit;
  if not Assigned(FBitmap) then Exit;
  // The event will ignore Empty frames      
  FBitmap.Canvas.Lock;
  try
    FBitmap.SaveToFile(Format('%.2d.bmp', [TGIFPainter(Sender).ActiveImage]));
  finally
    FBitmap.Canvas.Unlock;
  end;
  ProgressBar1.StepIt;
end;
```

Note: No error handling to simplify the code.

[image: output bitmaps]

---

**For newer Delphi Versions (2009+):**  With build-in `GIFImg` unit, you can do this quit easy with the use of [`TGIFRenderer`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_GIFImg_TGIFRenderer.html) (which completely replaced old `TGIFPainter`) e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
begin
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;      
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\test\test.gif');
    Bitmap.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);
    GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
    try
      for I := 0 to GIF.Images.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if GIF.Images[I].Empty then Break;
        GR.Draw(Bitmap.Canvas, Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);
        GR.NextFrame;
        Bitmap.SaveToFile(Format('%.2d.bmp', [I]));
      end;
    finally
      GR.Free;
    end;  
  finally
    GIF.Free;
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Using GDI+:**

```
uses ..., GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL;

procedure ExtractGifFrames(const FileName: string);
var
  GPImage: TGPImage;
  encoderClsid: TGUID;
  BmpFrame: TBitmap;
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
  FrameCount, FrameIndex: Integer;
begin
  GPImage := TGPImage.Create(FileName);
  try
    if GPImage.GetLastStatus = Ok then
    begin
      GetEncoderClsid('image/bmp', encoderClsid);
      FrameCount := GPImage.GetFrameCount(GDIPAPI.FrameDimensionTime);
      for FrameIndex := 0 to FrameCount - 1 do
      begin
        GPImage.SelectActiveFrame(GDIPAPI.FrameDimensionTime, FrameIndex);
        MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          if GPImage.Save(TStreamAdapter.Create(MemStream), encoderClsid) = Ok then
          begin
            MemStream.Position := 0;
            BmpFrame := TBitmap.Create;
            try
              BmpFrame.LoadFromStream(MemStream);
              BmpFrame.SaveToFile(Format('%.2d.bmp', [FrameIndex]));
            finally
              BmpFrame.Free;
            end;
          end;
        finally
          MemStream.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    GPImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent, the second example works for me perfectly (Delphi XE). I wish I could accept multiple answers in this scenario, thanks everyone. Studying this code makes it look easier than I had anticipated.

Comment: +1, I think using the renderer is the most natural way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The frames of an animated GIF file often only contain the differences from the previous frame (an optimisation technique to reduce file size). So in order to produce a snapshot of the GIF at a particular point, you'll have to paste all the frames up to that point, one after the other.

We can achieve this by using `Draw()` with its 'draw transparently' option set:

```
procedure ExtractGifFrames(FileName: string);
var
  Gif: TGifImage;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  i: Integer;
  Bounds: TRect;
begin
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  try
    Gif.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Bounds := Rect(0, 0, Gif.Width-1, Gif.Height-1);

    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.SetSize(Gif.Width, Gif.Height);
      Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

      for i := 0 to Gif.Images.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if not Gif.Images[i].Empty then
        begin
          Gif.Images[i].Draw(Bmp.Canvas, Bounds, True, True);
          Bmp.SaveToFile(IntToStr(i) + '.bmp');
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Gif.Free;
  end;
end;
```

NB: There are other elements to the animated GIF format, which specify the amount of times frames are to be repeated etc. but they may not concern you.

Comment: I forgot to mention I already tried that, no difference. It seems as though some frames in a gif only draw the extra bits, and use previous frames to draw the background?

Comment: Ok, have modified my answer :-)

Comment: I was actually close then regarding my last comment! Not sure how I could achieve this though?

Comment: Perhaps if you link to a URL with a GIF file you're having difficulty with, we can have a play and hopefully help you?

Comment: Almost correct, but try my testing transparent [`tiger`](http://www.flantech.net/images/animated.gif). It doesn't encouter with transparent images at all. Actually the same code I had before myself few hours before. Theoretically this might be resolved when you make the bitmap transparent and **find the key frame**. If you would know the key frame, you might start to render on a new bitmap, but how to find it, that's the problem.

Comment: Very good Steve, just the new problem TLama hit on that needs solving.

Comment: Heh - it worked with your sample gif, and I stopped there!  I'll have a look at the tiger when I get a moment.