# Issue with rebuilding and saving Gif's using TGIFImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have yet another problem regarding GifImage.pas that is included with Delphi XE. The issue I have sort of relates to a previous question I asked: [TGifImage Transparency Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349050/tgifimage-transparency-issue)

The problem from the previous question above was solved by using the TGifRenderer to display the correct frames from a Gif file which worked perfectly for loading.

But now I need to do the opposite, I need to rebuild and save a new Gif from a series of bitmaps. But when I save, the output Gif file draws incorrectly - just like before.

I am not sure if I need TGIfRenderer again or not because all I am doing is adding bitmaps and packing then saving the Gif.

To see the exact problem I am facing, please carry on reading (apologies in advance for the long post!)

**First save these bitmaps to a new sample project folder:**

**NOTE:** These images were originally bitmaps but StackOverflow seems to have converted them to PNG so you might need to copy into Paint and save again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now from a new project, paste the following code:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, GifImg, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Gif: TGIFImage;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Gif := TGIFImage.Create;
  try
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('img0.bmp');
    Bmp.Transparent := True;
    Gif.Add(Bmp);
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('img1.bmp');
    Bmp.Transparent := True;
    Gif.Add(Bmp);
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('img2.bmp');
    Bmp.Transparent := True;
    Gif.Add(Bmp);
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('img3.bmp');
    Bmp.Transparent := True;
    Gif.Add(Bmp);

    // add netscape loop if we want animation to keep repeating
    TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(Gif.Images.Frames[0]).Loops := 0;
    Gif.Pack;
    Gif.SaveToFile('test.gif');
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
    Gif.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Make sure the saved bitmaps are in the same folder as the project's exe (or change the filename paths) then run the project to create the output gif.

The saved output is not correct. From the penguin bitmaps saved above, I get this saved Gif:

[image]

You can see the frames are overlapping each other or something funky is going on! The source to this gif file can be found from here: http://www.animated-gifs.org.uk/agif/ani02.gif

I did not use all the frames from the Gif as there is so many, but you can see how it should work when animated.

Note that this does not happen with every gif, only a select few seem to save like this. Another example would be to try these bitmaps instead of the penguin:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The result is:

[image]

which should be (notice the flames on the plane):

[image]

To put it simply, I need to save a Gif from a series of bitmaps to be just like how they were when they were opened. You can see from the sample bitmaps above there is no inconsistency with the actual image data, so this makes me believe it is something to do with how they are added to the gif.

If I do need TGIfRenderer again I am not sure how to implement it for saving, I keep thinking it is for loading only?

This is one of those issues I get that I cannot solve. I've been trying to change the transparency and color and mode etc but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: not a duplicate, but possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349050/tgifimage-transparency-issue

Comment: @Leonardo - That's OP's own question which is also already linked in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: Ugh. How embarrassing. Anyways, it should have lead to the answer, right? :-)

Comment: To correctly read the gif frames TGifRenderer was used, and as Sertac has demonstrated in his answer the disposal of frames was needed to cleanly save the gif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert with GIFImg or gif images but the problem seems to be related with disposal of frames. Searching for 'disposal' in 'GIFImg.pas', I came up with the below which seems to work for your test image:

```
....
Gif.Add(Bmp); // last frame

for i := 0 to Gif.Images.Count - 1 do
  for j := 0 to Gif.Images[i].Extensions.Count - 1 do
    if Gif.Images[i].Extensions[j] is TGIFGraphicControlExtension then
      TGIFGraphicControlExtension(Gif.Images[i].Extensions[j]).Disposal :=
          dmBackground;
...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity when you search Gifimg.pas what made you find the answer? How did you determine that disposal was what we needed?

Comment: @Blobby - I knew a bit about disposal from when I was preparing gifs for web pages etc.. I verified it by saving test.gif through GIMP selecting 'replace' for 'Frame disposal'. Then I searched through GIFImg.pas to achieve the same. BTW, I have a feeling that, on some condition, a gif can have multiple 'Extensions', you may need to change the code a bit to iterate over extensions in the future if need may arise..

Comment: Very good. But I am not sure what you mean by some gifs can have multiple extensions. .Extension in gifimg.pas tells me it is TGIFExtensionList but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Well I couldn't find much information on Extensions (not to be confused with file extensions). What I did notice however is that if I use the `Extensions[0]).Disposal` as you showed above for bitmaps without transparency then the save errors with list out of bounds. So before calling `Gif.Add(Bmp);` if you make `Bmp.Transparent := False;` it errors when using disposal. If you comment out the disposal code the non transparent bitmaps save to gif perfectly. This would tell me the extensions has something to do with the type of gif been saved?

Comment: @Blobby - That should take care of the 'list out of bounds' error. However I believe you need to know beforehand what disposal method you should use. If frames represent individual self-contained images, then it should be 'replace'/'background', if they represent differential images, then better don't change frame disposal method.

Comment: Thanks for updating Sertac that seems to have fixed the out of bounds error. How would I determine if the the frames are `individual self-contained images` or `differential` ones? The gifs are loaded from file and each frame edited at runtime before finally saving. I am not sure when I should use dispose or not based on this.

Comment: @Blobby - Visually it should be easy (only parts of the frame would contain a non-transparent part of the image for all but the first frame), but programmatically I have no idea. Maybe you can let the user choose the appropriate method?..