# How to extract frames from a TGifImage into Bitmaps?

Tags: delphi, gif

The demo below tries to draw the GIF on form's canvas. It doesn't work. The image won't advance. How to make it work?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
 GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\2.gif');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 GIF.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR i: Integer;
begin
 REPEAT
  for i:= 0 to GIF.Images.Count-1 DO
   begin
    DisplayGifFrame(i);
    Sleep(30);
   end;
 UNTIL FALSE;
end;


procedure TForm1.DisplayGifFrame(AIndex: Integer);
VAR
   Renderer: TGIFRenderer;
begin
 Renderer := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
 TRY
  Renderer.Animate := TRUE;
  Renderer.FrameIndex := AIndex;
  Renderer.Draw(Canvas, Canvas.ClipRect); 

  {save frame in a bitmap here. save bitmap to disk}
  // xxx 
 FINALLY
  Renderer.Free;
 end;
end;
```

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to extract all frames from a GIF and put each frame IN A UNIQUE bitmap.

---

**Update:**
Continued here: [Cannot draw GIF on dynamically created TBitmap(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140614/cannot-draw-gif-on-tbitmap)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What problem are you having with the code you posted? What isn't working as you'd expect? Try reading your question from our point of view, remembering we know absolutely nothing about what your code is trying to do, what you think it should be doing, or any information about what's not working. Then please edit and add more details so we can try and get you help. :-)

Comment: I don't know who's downvoting so quickly, but please stop. Give the poster a few minutes to respond to comments and fix the question before deciding to downvote, especially when people have already asked them to do so. @Altar: "It doesn't work" means absolutely nothing to anyone but you. **Please read my last comment again**.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks Ken for calming down the herd :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;      
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\test\test.gif');
    Bitmap.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);
    GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
    try
      for I := 0 to GIF.Images.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if GIF.Images[I].Empty then Break;
        GR.Draw(Bitmap.Canvas, Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);
        GR.NextFrame;
        Bitmap.SaveToFile(Format('%.2d.bmp', [I]));
      end;
    finally
      GR.Free;
    end;  
  finally
    GIF.Free;
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The above code takes into account Frame's `Disposal` method. see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10349050/937125).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will this work also with interlaced GIF images ?

Comment: No, `Update` wouldn't help. There are no "draw messages" that need to be processed before drawing occurs. Painting to a canvas is essentially immediate. `Update` tells a window that it should immediately paint itself, but all that means is that it will draw to its canvas, which is what `GR.Draw` is doing anyway.

Comment: @Altar You wanted to save frame bitmaps in your initial Q. I don't understand what's your objective now.

Comment: @TLama, I think you refer to frame `Disposal` method, which this code takes into account.