# Cannot draw GIF on dynamically created TBitmap(s)

Tags: delphi

I want to extract frames of a GIF image. The code below works, but it's not what I need. I need to keep the extracted frames in a series of bitmaps.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
  TRY
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\1.gif');
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;       <------------ one single object, reused
    Bitmap.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);
    GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
    try
      for I := 0 to GIF.Images.Count - 1 do
       begin    
         GR.Draw(Bitmap.Canvas, Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);

         Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bitmap);

         GR.NextFrame;
       end;
    finally
      GR.Free;
    end;
  finally
    GIF.Free;
    //Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

So I dynamically create a bitmap for each frame. But this won't work. It will only show the same/first frame in all bitmaps!

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
  TRY
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\1.gif');
    GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
    try
      for I := 0 to GIF.Images.Count - 1 do
       begin
         Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;       <----- multiple bitmaps, one for each frame
         Bitmap.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);

         GR.Draw(Bitmap.Canvas, Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);

         Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bitmap);

         GR.NextFrame;
       end;
    finally
      GR.Free;
    end;

    {TODO: store bitmaps in a TObjectList for later use 
    List.Add(Bitmap);  }     
  finally
    GIF.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What is wrong with the above piece of code? Maybe TGIFRenderer draws ONLY the differences between frames?

---

**UPDATE for TLama/jachguate:**

TLama says that the code doesn't work because I don't free the bitmaps. I don't want to free the bitmaps. I need them later. Here is some (demo-grade) code.

```
VAR List: TObjectList;    {used and freed somwhere else}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  UniqueBMP: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  List:= TObjectList.Create;
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
  TRY
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\1.gif');

    GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
    try
      for I := 0 to GIF.Images.Count - 1 do
       begin
         UniqueBMP := TBitmap.Create;
         UniqueBMP.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);

         if GIF.Images[I].Empty then Break;

         GR.Draw(UniqueBMP.Canvas, UniqueBMP.Canvas.ClipRect);

         Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, UniqueBMP);
         Sleep(50);

         List.Add(UniqueBMP);

         GR.NextFrame;
       end;
    finally
      GR.Free;
    end;
  finally
    GIF.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.btnFreeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  FreeAndNil(List);
end;
```

Comment: I KNOW! Please ignore it! It's just a demo. It's not relevant to our current problem :)

Comment: Doesn't work explains nothing, but I'd suspect frame interlacing. My guess is that renderer draws the frame exactly as it is (why wouldn't, anyway) and since you use always a new bitmap for each frame, you can get (visually) almost empty bitmap because (visually) the rest must be rendered by the underlying frames. In other words, you need to use one bitmap and let renderer draw the layers for you. But, it's just my guess.

Comment: @TLama - I thought the same, but the GIF image that I use is pretty animated. There are many differences between frames. I should be able to see something in the next frames....

Comment: Could you upload that image somewhere (imgur.com e.g.) and include the link to your question, please ? Except rendering interlaced frame I can't find any other sensible reason, why the two code samples might differ in results.

Comment: Here is the image (deadly funny): http://imgur.com/COd6uUQ

Comment: If you'd properly free the `Bitmap` object, then the rendering works properly. The question is then, why... You're assigning a new instance of the object, but it seems like renderer works with the previous one. In other words, use `try..finally` block and `Free` the `Bitmap` there.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me in XE3, but I already added the code to free the bitmaps.

Comment: @TLama you must post it as an answer, since you commented it first.

Comment: I don't want to free the unique bitmaps. I need (I was going to) to put them in an object list.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me: the TGIFRenderer caches a reference to the Canvas in the **`FCanvas`** strict private field. Then, the `TCustomGIFRenderer.Draw` method starts with: `if (FCanvas <> ACanvas)`, but it happens that when the Bitmap is freed, the new Bitmap is created in the same address and then, the renderer `Reset` and `Initialize` methods are not called, so the animation _works_, thanks to the bug.

Comment: @jachguate, no, `Reset` and `Initialize` are called when you create a new bitmap and `Draw` on it. That's the reason, why Altar got always just the first frame.

Comment: @TLama, if you free the bitmap (after each frame) and create a new one (before each frame), it works: you get the complete sequence, and not only the first frame, but it happens to happen because there's a bug and the new Bitmap (and it's canvas) is in the same address, so the cached reference is _the same_ and the if condition doesn't met, thus Reset and Initialize is not called for the 2nd to the last frame.

Comment: @jachguate, you're saying that the comparison `if (FCanvas <> ACanvas) then` passes because of the same object memory address, but it shouldn't pass at least because of different `HDC` (`Canvas.Handle`) that this bitmap get (well, there's a chance that you can get even already used `HDC`, but it's very small to confirm your theory).

Comment: @TLama, _yes_. That's why it works when you Free and then Create, but doesn't work when you just create and create without freeing. IMHO that's a bug, because the Renderer is caching a pointer to the canvas without (for example) a proper implementation of a FreeNotification mechanism to get aware of when the canvas is freed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TCustomGIFRenderer.Draw` checks the canvas on which is going to render. If it differs from the one which it remembers from the last rendering (and it differs, since you're creating the new bitmap for each frame), the `TCustomGIFRenderer.Reset` method is called, which, as its name explains, resets the frame index to 0. That's why you're getting rendered always just the first frame.

Comment: Thanks TLama for the explanation. No thanks to Embarcadero for their 'great' user manual.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, this should have been mentioned in docs or better implemented in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

**Working code based on TLama's solution (please vote his post not mine):**

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  TempBMP, UniqueBMP: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
  TRY
    GIF.LoadFromFile('c:\1.gif');

    TempBMP := TBitmap.Create;       <------- SOLUTION
    TempBMP.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);

    GR := TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);
    try
      for I := 0 to GIF.Images.Count - 1 do
       begin
         UniqueBMP := TBitmap.Create;      <------- SOLUTION
         UniqueBMP.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);

         if GIF.Images[I].Empty then Break;

         GR.Draw(TempBMP.Canvas, TempBMP.Canvas.ClipRect);

         UniqueBMP.Assign(TempBMP);                <------- SOLUTION
         Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, UniqueBMP);
         Sleep(50);

         GR.NextFrame;
       end;
    finally
      GR.Free;
    end;
  finally
    GIF.Free;
    TempBMP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This solution is fine. To let the renderer draw the frame of current index you have to use for the `GR.Draw` method call the same canvas and the same rectangle. Once either of those parameter differs from the first `GR.Draw` method call, the frame index is reset to the first frame.